# Certain key mappings not working in MacVim

Tags: macos, vim, keyboard-shortcuts, keymapping

I've recently switched to using a Mac at work from previously using Linux. I found out about MacVim (from http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) and have been trying to port over my previous keymappings.

The mappings I used to have are as follows:

- <kbd>Ctrl-T</kbd>: New tab
- <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd>: Close tab/window
- <kbd>Ctrl-1</kbd> ... <kbd>Ctrl-0</kbd>: Switch to numbered tab
- <kbd>Alt-Up</kbd>: New tab (same as <kbd>Ctrl-T</kbd>)
- <kbd>Alt-Left</kbd>/<kbd>Alt-Right</kbd>: Switch to the previous/next tab
- <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-E</kbd>: Open FuzzyFinder in file mode
- <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-B</kbd>: Open FuzzyFinder in buffer mode
- <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-W</kbd>: Clear trailing whitespace from the buffer

Now, to make these mappings more 'Mac like', I decided to switch the first two to use the option (ie. Apple logo) key, and all the others to use the command key instead of Alt (ie. <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-E</kbd> becomes <kbd>Ctrl-Command-E</kbd>). I read on http://macvim.org/OSX/index.php that this key can be mapped with D (ie ). The new contents of my .vimrc is as follows:

```
nmap <D-t> :tabnew<cr>
nmap <D-w> :close<cr>
nmap <D-1> 1gt
nmap <D-2> 2gt
nmap <D-3> 3gt
nmap <D-4> 4gt
nmap <D-5> 5gt
nmap <D-6> 6gt
nmap <D-7> 7gt
nmap <D-8> 8gt
nmap <D-9> 9gt
nmap <D-0> 10gt

nmap <D-Up> :tabnew<CR>
nmap <D-Right> :tabnext<CR>
nmap <D-Left> :tabprevious<CR>

"FuzzyFinder
nmap <C-D-e> :FufFileWithFullCwd<CR>
nmap <C-D-b> :FufBuffer<CR>

"Whitespace remover
nmap <C-D-w> :%s/\s\+$//<CR>
```

So, after re-mapping the keys, some now work and others don't, with no clear logic as to why.

What works:

- <kbd>Cmd-T</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd-W</kbd> successfully work for opening and closing tabs.
- <kbd>Cmd-1</kbd> ... <kbd>Cmd-0</kbd> successfully work for switching tabs.

What doesn't work:

- <kbd>Cmd-Up</kbd> for opening a tab does not work.
- <kbd>Cmd-Left</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd-Right</kbd> for switching tabs does not work.
- <kbd>Ctrl-Cmd-E</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-Cmd-B</kbd> for opening FuzzyFinder do not work.
- <kbd>Ctrl-Cmd-W</kbd> for clearing whitespace does not work (but neither does it close the tab, as it would without <kbd>ctrl</kbd>.

Comment: you can accept your own answer if you found the solution yourself. ;)

Comment: There is a [reason](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html) to always use `*nore(map|abbrev)` (e.g. `nnoremap`) and never `nmap`.

Comment: Thanks ZyX for the advice. I think I'm going to read the whole of 'Learn Vim Script the Hard Way' when I get the chance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it turns out that there is a bug in Macvim (http://code.google.com/p/macvim/issues/detail?id=317) which means it's not possible to map the ctrl key. Instead I mapped the leader key (a.k.a. the backslash), and it all seems to work now.

Comment: Hi @Joel Cross could you tell me how you solved that problem more specifically? I try to map a key to ctrl+command+w. thanks

Comment: Hi Joel, could you tell me more details how to map ctrl+command+w ?

Comment: Sorry I mean map a key like F to ctrl+command+w, not vice versa

Answer (score 7):

Investigate the cause by doing

```
:verbose map <D-Up>
```

Additionally try selectively enabling your other plugins to see whether mappings are being cleared somehow

Comment: <D-Up>      * <C-Home>
    Last set from /Applications/MacPorts/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/gvimrc

Comment: So it would seem that a global file is overriding my config. I'm surprised though, because I would have thought my user config would take precedence.

Comment: I added the line "let macvim_skip_cmd_opt_movement = 1" to my .vimrc and now the tabs are working fine. The Last three commands (the ones using the ctrl-cmd combination) still aren't working though.

Comment: So it turns out that there is a bug in Macvim (http://code.google.com/p/macvim/issues/detail?id=317) which means it's not possible to map the ctrl key. Until that is fixed, I will try mapping the shift key instead.

Comment: @JoelCross: good work. Please consider posting your answer so people can use it in the future. Was my answer helpful in any way?

Comment: Unfortunately as a StackOverflow newbie I have to wait another 7 hours before I can post an answer, hence all the comments on your answer. Yes, your answer solved half of my problem.